How to use a .pd file and integrate with a tensorflow model?
First I have a gzipped file named maia-1900.pb.gz, I unzipped it by double clicking on mac and a file named maia-1900.pb was outputted. I tried loading the model with model = tf.saved_model.load("maia-1900") but I got an error saying: OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: maia-1900/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb} .
Then I realized that the file may be a frozen graph file and I tried to convert the frozen graph to a tensorflow model. I first tested out to see the nodes of the graph to find the input and output tensor by using this code:
import tensorflow as tf

def load_frozen_graph(pb_file):
    with tf.io.gfile.GFile(pb_file, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
        return graph

def print_all_nodes(graph):
    """Print all nodes in the graph."""
    for op in graph.get_operations():
        print(op.name)

def main(pb_file):
    """Main function to load the graph and print all nodes."""
    graph = load_frozen_graph(pb_file)
    print_all_nodes(graph)

# Path to the frozen graph file
pb_file_path = 'maia-1900.pb'

# Run the script
main(pb_file_path)


But I wasn't able to find it and it kept saying that the graph had 0 nodes. I am very confused because the .pb file is definitely not an empty file. Please help me on how to integrate this .pb file with a tensorflow/keras model.
Thank you very much
